# Markdown Table not working (kramdown)

Tags: github, formatting, markdown, jekyll

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Prh.png)

Its working perfectly in the atom md preview but it outputs terribly in Github hosted jekyll website?

My posted md file online:
https://kevin-do.github.io//aztec-parking/

Could someone please help?

Comment: Screenshots are completely useless when helping someone debug their Markdown. Try [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40095861/edit) your question and including the offending Markdown in a code block. It also might help to point to your Jekyll config.

Comment: If it helps, Kramdown's table documentation is [here](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#tables).

Comment: gotcha I'll keep that in mind, sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Atom Markdown preview does not use Kramdown, Jekyll does. There are so many different-but-similar Markdown variants that you probably haven't noticed until now.

That said, in this case it's probably the `---` at the start. Change it to`|---`, and add a blank line in between the table and the heading.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a bunch